# Como Hago para modificar los valores de una columna en la siguiente consulta

Tags: java, sql

el profesor me dijo que tocaba poner una columna inactivo que sea de tipo boolean y que cuando este sea menor que marque false

Eliminar aquellos empleados que ganan menos de 500000, son hombres y pertenecen al departamento entre el 1 y el 3, se pueden eliminar siempre y cuando sean de la sección 2.

el codigo que deduje es esté

```
select * 
from "Empleado" 
where salario_empleado < 500000 = "Inactivo_empleado" = false
```

pero no me quiere dar la parte en que cambia a inactivo

Comment: es decir seleccionar a los empleados que ganan menos de 5000, que su departamento sea del 1 al 3 y que el estado inactivo sea false?

Comment: si pudieras por favor editar con base a [ask], colocar un ejemplo de lo que tratas de obtener y ampliar un poco mejor la pregunta

Comment: Eliminar aquellos empleados que ganan menos de 500000, son hombres y pertenecen al departamento entre el 1 y el 3, se pueden eliminar siempre y cuando sean de la sección 2. este es el query amigo

Comment: osea ya elminar ya no se utiliza segun el profesor entonces remplazand esto me dijo creara una columna inactivo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que lo que necesitas es algo así:

```
update Empleado set Inactivo_empleado = true where salario_empleado < 500000 and Inactivo_empleado = false and departamento_empleado >= 1 and departamento_empleado <= 3 and genero_empleado = "hombre" and seleccion_empleado = 2
```

Esto pondrá como inactivos (Inactivo_empleado = true) todos los empleados ganen menos de 500000, pertenezcan a un departamento que este entre el 1 y el 3, sean hombres y pertenezcan a la sección 2.

Desconozco los nombrees de todas las columnas pero seria algo así.

Comment: gracias eso era